# Using OpenCV FileStorage to read a XML file

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

I am trying to use FileStorage to read a XML file with this code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {    
  cv::FileStorage fs("/Users/thewoz/Desktop/01.xml", cv::FileStorage::READ);  
  return 0;  
}
```

The gives me the following error:

`persistence.cpp:706: error: (-5:Bad argument) Input file is invalid in function 'open'`

This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<images>
"20170720_024951.jpg"
"20170720_025001.jpg"
"20170720_025014.jpg"
"20170720_025023.jpg"
"20170720_025034.jpg"
"20170720_025048.jpg"
"20170720_025103.jpg"
"20170720_025115.jpg"
"20170720_025124.jpg"
"20170720_025133.jpg"
"20170720_025147.jpg"
"20170720_025155.jpg"
"20170720_025211.jpg"
</images>
```

I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: @Raffallo huh? Why???

Comment: You are missing an ampersand before fs.  See https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d56/classcv_1_1FileStorage.html

Comment: @jdweng sorry i don't understand what you mean

Comment: @jdweng which ampersand where? You mean like here `cv::FileStorage & fs("/Users/...` ? That looks wrong to me.

Comment: Look at link.  The ampersand is the address of fs.

Comment: @jdweng I am trying hard to understand what you are saying but I can't understand it all the way. could you write down how the code should be modified?

Comment: @thewoz I have no idea what jdweng is talking about either. However, I am unable to reproduce your problem (get an error about some missing tags, but it identifies the file correctly as XML, unlike in your case). What version of OpenCV is it? Based on the style of error message, I guess it's not one of the recent ones.

Comment: Looking in persistence.cpp, it looks like it was not able to read the file. Do you have the correct permissions? to discard the basic stuff try to open it with `std::ifstream file(path);` and then check if it is open with `file.is_open()`.

Comment: Are you sure those are the exact contents of that XML file? For example a single space in front of the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` part will break things (resulting in "Input file is invalid" error), the only thing allowed to precede it is BOM.

Comment: @DanMašek  which version do you use? I am using the code taken from GitHub. My  GitHub directory is set in this way remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/4.x anyway should be 4.9.0

Comment: @DanMašek yes i'm pretty sure the file starts correctly. i don't see any characters before <?xml

Comment: @api55 I checked and there is no problem in opening the file

Comment: @thewoz Never mind regarding the error message, turns out there are two ways it can format it...

Comment: [crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159) and answer: https://forum.opencv.org/t/using-opencv-filestorage-to-read-a-xml-file/16812

Comment: @jdweng show us specifically what you mean. I think you're mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV does not read *arbitrary* XML. With some changes to your file, it could read the file. If you can't change your file, you'll need to use a generic XML library.

`cv::FileStorage` is made specifically to store and read OpenCV types (e.g. `cv::Mat`). It assumes a specific structure to the file. This is specific to `cv::FileStorage`. One such requirement is that all the data is contained in a `<opencv_storage>` tag.

---

If you can change your file's format to fit `cv::FileStorage`, then sure, you can use it to read the file.

`cv:FileStorage` to write a list of strings:

```py
# images = ['20170720_024951.jpg', '20170720_025001.jpg', '20170720_025014.jpg', '20170720_025023.jpg', '20170720_025034.jpg', '20170720_025048.jpg', '20170720_025103.jpg', '20170720_025115.jpg', '20170720_025124.jpg', '20170720_025133.jpg', '20170720_025147.jpg', '20170720_025155.jpg', '20170720_025211.jpg']

fs = cv.FileStorage(
    "opencv-filestorage.xml",
    cv.FileStorage_WRITE | cv.FileStorage_FORMAT_XML)
fs.write("images", images)
fs.release()
```

Pardon the Python, C++ would be mostly equivalent.

The XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<images>
  "20170720_024951.jpg" "20170720_025001.jpg" "20170720_025014.jpg"
  "20170720_025023.jpg" "20170720_025034.jpg" "20170720_025048.jpg"
  "20170720_025103.jpg" "20170720_025115.jpg" "20170720_025124.jpg"
  "20170720_025133.jpg" "20170720_025147.jpg" "20170720_025155.jpg"
  "20170720_025211.jpg"</images>
</opencv_storage>
```

*That format* you *can* read with `cv::FileStorage`.

```py
fs = cv.FileStorage(
    "opencv-filestorage.xml",
    cv.FileStorage_READ | cv.FileStorage_FORMAT_XML)
node = fs.getNode("images")
assert node.isSeq()
print(node.size(), "images")
assert all(
    node.at(i).isString() for i in range(node.size()))
images = [
    node.at(i).string()
    for i in range(node.size())
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and sorry for the crosspost